# Rails::Application.initialize! method source location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find the source for following line in my blog application's environment.rb

```
Blog::Application.initialize!
```

If found that the initialize! method is defined only in one place in the source code.

*railties/lib/rails/application.rb*

```
def initialize!(group=:default) #:nodoc:
  raise "Application has been already initialized." if @initialized
```

However it is an instance method.

I did some experiments in the rails console:

```
Blog::Application.initialize!  # => Application has been already initialized
Blog::Application.method(:initialize!)  # => undefined method for Class
Blog::Application.instance_methods.include?(:initialize!)  # => true
```

Its strange that we get an undefined method for `initialize!` when it is clearly callable on the Application class. Please help in understanding this code.

Comment: If it is an instance method of `Blog::Application`, then you would not be able to call `Blog::Application.initialize!`. Your description is contradictory.

Comment: @sawa https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/code/getting_started/config/environment.rb or try creating a new rails app.

Comment: No I will not. I will not follow your order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to some Ruby Magic aka "Method Missing":

```
Blog::Application.ancestors
=> [... Rails::Railtie::Configurable ...]
```

Have a look at `configurable.rb`:

```
module Rails
  class Railtie
    module Configurable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      module ClassMethods
        [...]

        def method_missing(*args, &block)
          instance.send(*args, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

it delegtes all the calls to the underlying application instance.

Comment: That makes sense and answers my question. However, I am having difficulty understanding how Rails::Railtie::Configurable is included in Blog::Application. It does not show up among the ancestors of Rails::Application. It would be helpful if you can edit the answer to point that out.